# How do can I create a bitcoin wallet with a already created address and private key?

Tags: wallet

I have a bitcoin address and a private key. What wallet can I use to import the key and address I already have? Every wallet I tried only lets you create a new address or use a 12 world recovery phase to access another wallet.

What wallet will let me directly import my private key & address?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core supports importing private keys. Use the `importprivkey` RPC.

Answer (score 0):

I know electrum lets you import private keys. I did this with the portable version but I assume thats its the same with the installed version.

Answer (score 0):

Jaxx allows this: [howto-link](https://decentral.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217877418-How-do-I-transfer-funds-from-a-paper-wallet-private-key-)

Or Exodus: [howto-link](http://support.exodus.io/knowledge_base/topics/can-i-import-a-private-key)

Both support multiple currencies. I would look at this [list of wallets](https://www.cryptocompare.com/wallets/#/overview) and if you find one that you like just google "*walletname* import private  keys" too see if it's possible and how to do it.